# Add automatically the quotation marks inside a string in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I am in python and I want to add the quotation marks inside a string. Concretely, I have the following string:

```
'{name:robert,surname:paul}'
```

And I want to programmatically get the following, operating on the first

```
'{name:"robert",surname:"paul"}'
```

Is there any efficient way to perform this?

Comment: the first code example won't work. Are you talking about string replacement in your python coding environment (text editor, ...)?

Comment: @offeltoffel, what do you mean it won't work? That's a syntactically valid string literal.

Comment: Presumably you're getting a string of key/value pairs right now, and you want some function `f` which, on an input like `f("""{a:b,c:d}""")` returns the string `"""{a:"b",c:"d"}"""`. Can I ask why you want this? Whilst what you're after is possible, it feels a bit like you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: I'm confused on whether you want to programmatically add the quotation marks or asking about how you could do `'{name:'robert',surname:'paul'}'` without having errors?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to do it manually obviously. I just want to take the first string and obtain the second automatically..

Answer (score 8):

Use a regex to match word `\w*` after `:` and replace it using backreference `\1` :

Prefix your `regex`string by `r` (raw string) to automatically escape characters.

https://repl.it/Nh29/1

```
import re

input_str='{name:robert,surname:paul}'

output_str=re.sub(r':(\w*)', r':"\1"', input_str )

print output_str
```

will produce

```
{name:"robert",surname:"paul"}
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it is ok for you. thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
def literalize(string):
    string = string[1:-1].split(',')
    string = map(lambda s: str.split(s, ':'), string)
    return_string = ''
    for item in string:
            return_string += '%s: "%s", ' % tuple(item)
    return "{%s}" % return_string
```

I wouldn't ever consider this a masterpiece but I've tried not to use RegEx for this; however it ended up being messy and bodgy, and obviously factorizable with list comprehensions and what not.

Some implementation details are that it won't work very well when the `value` has a comma or colon inside, and another implementation detail being that `tuple(item)` can be replaced by `(*item)` if you prefer a more Python 3 way.

```
 >>> literalize(a)
'{name: "robert", surname: "paul", }'
```

Note: I don't think the redundant `,` at the end should matter too much when parsing using something like `json.loads(...)`